# How do I use the permanent unlock token?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I prestiged. I'm at level 16 and I see no way to permanently unlock a weapon or perk. Where is this located?

Answer (score 3):

For Xbox 360, once you have your unlock token after prestiging, just go to the weapon / perk and press RB (you might be able to press LB too).

RB is the button above the right trigger (I think it stands for Right Bump).

For PS3, the button is R1.

Comment: Yup, RB *and* LB work. On PS3, I guess it's L1/R1.

Comment: Um, only R1 works for PS3.